# how to structurize AWS Serverless application?

Tags: aws-lambda, architecture

I found out nano services it looks like the appropriate architecture for AWS lambdas
is that true, or should I stick with a classic microservices architecture?

Comment: Neither approach is inherently better than the other.  What matters is "what problem are you trying to solve", and the context / constraints that apply.  Only then can you work out which solution matches your problem.  Provide some more info on your problem and constraints, the more you provide the better answers here will be.

Comment: ok, let's assume we do some stuff management app
1. We can buy different app packs(like free/pro/ultimate versions)
2. You can manage employees(CRUD ops)
3. You can schedule employee's work(Alex works from 2pm to 5pm  on project A
4. Notify employees when new activity take place
5. Inventory management
and so on.

just to clarify, nanoservices looks pretty attractive for me
1. you can granuate and isolate your nanoservices, each  worker can work on their own nanoserivces and doesn't have to understand whole legacy code
2. Easier scalability
3. Instant deployment

Comment: 4. Represent your logic(or combine) with AWS Step Function(you can see logic flow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AWS lambda's are not a complete architecture, they are merely a component.

The functionality you described in your comment would need a full-stack solution, because you need to manage state, etc.  Classic microservices sounds like a safer approach because:

- It's a more well understood architecture, so there will be more resources you can leverage.  At this stage, from the little reading I have done, nano seems a bit "flavor of the month".
- Microservices are much closer to providing a full stack, where as AWS lambdas are only part of it.  With a microservices architecture you'll be more consciously considering a wider range of technical aspects.

If you decide to take the lamdba approach You'll have "nano" architecture based on lambdas, and everything else.  Not sure how good an architecture that will be - because it won't be "balanced" if you put all your focus on the lambdas.  Architecture needs to be holistic, if you are too preoccupied with lambdas you will miss other important things, or and try and use lambdas where a different approach would have been better.